# Convert file from base64 and send to some external service as binary file

Tags: node.js, file, rest

I send file to node.js server as base64 string, then I need to send it to the external service as binary file. Is it possible to do that without saving file to a file system? Now I'm trying get file on node.js side in this way:

```
var fileData    = req.body.value,
    fileName    = req.body.id,
    base64Data  = fileData.replace(/^data:image\/jpeg;base64,/,"");

modules.fs.writeFile(
     fileName, 
     base64Data, 
     'base64', 
     function(err) 
     {
         if (err)
         {
             console.log(err);
         }
         else
         {
             //read file from the file system and send to the external service 
         }
     });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write it to a buffer:

```
var buffer = new Buffer(base64Data, 'base64');
```

An alternative would be something like https://github.com/cjblomqvist/base64Stream

Comment: But I need binary file, not a string.

Comment: @IvanSidorenko toString changes encoding from base64 to utf8. Try toString("binary");

Comment: @user568109: `binary` is deprecated. If you need a file, just use the buffer,

Comment: @IvanSidorenko: Buffers act like files.